# Inverted parentheses in RTL text in LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, hebrew, bidi, parentheses

I want to typeset Hebrew (RTL) text (either within LTR paragraphs or in its own RTL paragraphs) in LuaLaTeX. I manage to do this well with XeLaTeX using the `bidi` package, but when I use LuaLaTeX’s bidi support (§2.3 in the [LuaTeX manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/doc/luatex/luatex.pdf)) the parentheses in the RTL text are come out wrong, inverted.

For example, compare this good output:
[image: XeLaTeX’s (good) output]
of this file, compiled with XeLaTeX:

```
%! TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec, bidi}
\setmainfont{Alef}
\newcommand{\Heb}[1]{\RL{\fontspec[Script=Hebrew, Language=Hebrew]{Alef}#1}}

\begin{document}
Alpha (Beta) Gamma;
\Heb{אלף (בית) גימל};
A (B) C
\end{document}
```

… with this bad output:
[image: LuaLaTeX’s (bad) output]
of this file, compiled with LuaLaTeX:

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Alef}
\newcommand{\Heb}[1]{\bgroup\textdir TRT\fontspec[Script=Hebrew, Language=Hebrew]{Alef}#1\egroup}

\begin{document}
Alpha (Beta) Gamma;
\Heb{אלף (בית) גימל};
A (B) C
\end{document}
```

It seems the `bidi` package knows to invert brackets within RTL text. How can I have the same effect with LuaLaTeX?

Many thanks! :-)

---

**Update**: David Purton’s answer seems to solve the problem. Is there a solution which doesn’t involve using `babel`?

Comment: Have a look at http://wiki.luatex.org/index.php/Mirror_characters_with_Bidi_Mirrored_property

Comment: Although, I can't actually make the above link work...

Comment: It works with LuaTeX but not with LuaLaTeX. You need to have [`char-def.lua`](https://web.archive.org/web/20160322043734/http://source.contextgarden.net/tex/context/base/char-def.lua) in addition to the linked `mirror.lua`.

Comment: BTW, `bidi` does not invert the brackets, it is a feature of the engine (XeTeX). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/686959/264024

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `babel`. As of version 3.19, you don't even have to mark up for simple things. See §1.27 of the `babel` manual.

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=en-AU,main,mapfont=direction]{australian}
\babelprovide[import=he,mapfont=direction]{hebrew}
\babelfont{rm}[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
Alpha (Beta) Gamma;
אלף (בית) גימל;
A (B) C
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I wasn’t aware `babel` supports LuaLaTeX. For older versions or when explicit marking is preferred one can use the `bidi=basic-r`, with `\foreignlanguage` (inline) and `\foreignlanguage*` (paragraph) in the text.

Comment: @JúdaRonén, No, `bidi=basic-r` is only if your main language is RTL. It can behave a bit oddly if your main language is LTR. `babel`'s bidi support is a fast moving target at the moment. I would always try and use the most recent version you can. You can still use `\foreignlanguage` and `\selectlanguage`, etc. with `bidi=basic`.

Answer (score 1):

To answer you update, to make the code you linked in the comments to work with latex you need to replace `callback.register` with `luatexbase.add_to_callback`, since latex does not support `callback.register`.

Another change is to replace the line `if n.id == node.id("whatsit") and n.subtype == 7 then`, since a dir node are not a whatsit node anymore.

The file `char-def.lua` cannot be found in the linked code anymore, but I found it [here](https://github.com/adityam/context-math/blob/master/char-def.lua). Here is an example file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\directlua{
```

```lua
require("char-def.lua")

local function mirror(hlist)
    local rtl = false
    if tex.textdir == "TRT" then
        rtl = true
    elseif tex.textdir == "TLT" then
        rtl = false
    end
    for n in node.traverse(hlist) do
        if n.id == node.id('hlist') then
            mirror(n.list)
        end
        if n.id == node.id("dir") then
            if n.dir == "+TRT" or n.dir == "-TLT" then
                rtl = true
            elseif n.dir == "-TRT" or n.dir == "+TLT" then
                rtl = false
            end
        end
        if n.id == node.id('glyph') then
            if rtl then
                local char = n.char
                local mirror = characters.data[char].mirror
                if mirror then
                    n.char = mirror
                end
            end
        end
    end
end

luatexbase.add_to_callback('pre_linebreak_filter',
    function(h)
        mirror(h)
        return true
    end,
'mirror')
```

```latex
}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Alef}
\newcommand{\Heb}[1]{\bgroup\textdir TRT\fontspec[Script=Hebrew, Language=Hebrew]{Alef}#1\egroup}
\begin{document}
    Alpha (Beta) Gamma;
    \Heb{אלף (בית) גימל};
    A (B) C
\end{document}
```

Another option is to use babel's data file, without the package itself. The code is pretty much the same, just few adjustments are needed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\directlua{
```

```lua
require("babel-data-bidi.lua")

local function mirror(hlist)
    local rtl = false
    if tex.textdir == "TRT" then
        rtl = true
    elseif tex.textdir == "TLT" then
        rtl = false
    end
    for n in node.traverse(hlist) do
        if n.id == node.id('hlist') then
            mirror(n.list)
        end
        if n.id == node.id("dir") then
            if n.dir == "+TRT" or n.dir == "-TLT" then
                rtl = true
            elseif n.dir == "-TRT" or n.dir == "+TLT" then
                rtl = false
            end
        end
        if n.id == node.id('glyph') then
            if rtl then
                local char = n.char
                local mirror = Babel.characters[char]
                if mirror then
                    n.char = mirror.m
                end
            end
        end
    end
end

luatexbase.add_to_callback('pre_linebreak_filter',
    function(h)
        mirror(h)
        return true
    end,
'mirror')
```

```
}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Alef}
\newcommand{\Heb}[1]{\bgroup\textdir TRT\fontspec[Script=Hebrew, Language=Hebrew]{Alef}#1\egroup}
\begin{document}
    Alpha (Beta) Gamma;
    \Heb{אלף (בית) גימל};
    A (B) C
\end{document}
```

Both produce the following:

[image]

As a side note, it is preferable to not use `standalone` class for MWE's