# How does TeX display words in RTL languages?

Tags: arabic, opentype, bidi

This is likely a newb question, but I'm wondering how TeX automatically understands a language is RTL.

This is my test program:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\arabicfont}[Language=Default,Script=Arabic]{Cairo}
\begin{document}
\arabicfont العربية \par
\arabicfont ا ل ع ر ب ي ة \par
\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

I didn't use a package such as `bidi`, and I didn't mention things like RTL anywhere in the code, but the letters are already displayed in the correct order when put together. Is it the font or the TeX engine that is doing the magic here? (The order of multiple words in a paragraph is wrong, but the order of letters within one word is correct.)

(I think the webpage also has some magic with code display. The letters in the source code are written in the LTR order, the same as the second line in the output.)

Answer (score 1):

You did not mentioned which engine you are using, but I'm guessing you are using `XeTeX`.

`XeTeX` applies [Unicode BiDi algorithm](https://unicode.org/reports/tr9/), but only per word (or for bigger chunks of text if `\XeTeXinterwordspaceshaping` is positive) when a modern font is used (see the *last comment* to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/673113/264024)).

Consider the following code (to be compiled with `XeTeX`, not `XeLaTeX`,
note that the `\TeXXeTstate` needs to be positive to use the `\beginR` and `\endR` primitives, which dictate the text direction):

```
\TeXXeTstate1

\beginR Hello World\endR

\bye
```

The output is unsurprisingly

[image]

But, remember that plain TeX loads cmr10 by default, which is not a modern font. By loading the opentype version of Latin Modern we will get

```
\font\test="Latin Modern Roman 10 Regular" at 10pt

\TeXXeTstate1

\beginR Hello World\endR

\bye
```

[image]

And as you can see, the text rendered as left to right, but only per word, since latin letters are considered as strong LTR bu the unicode BiDi algorithm.

By increasing `\XeTeXinterwordspaceshaping` you can also apply unicode BiDi algorithm for whole sentences

```
\font\test="Latin Modern Roman 10 Regular" at 10pt\test
\XeTeXinterwordspaceshaping=2
\TeXXeTstate=1

\beginR Hello World\endR

\bye
```

[image]

More interesting example with mixed english and herew text (sorry, I don't know any arabic) which renders correctly without the need of any directional nodes

```
\font\test="David CLM Medium" at 10pt\test
\XeTeXinterwordspaceshaping=2
\TeXXeTstate=1

Hello World שלום עולם, Just some text סתם קצת טקסט

\bye
```

[image]

but I don't think you can an RTL paragraph without the use of the directionality primitives.