# Does XeLaTeX modify the \beginR premitive?

Tags: xetex, tex-core, right-to-left, primitives

Consider the following code

```
\TeXXeTstate=1

Hello World

\beginR Hello World\endR

\bye
```

Which produce the following document with either `XeTeX` or `pdfTeX`

[image]

Now, the out put of the following code is the same with `pdfLaTeX`

```
\documentclass{article}

\TeXXeTstate=1

\begin{document}

Hello World

\beginR Hello World\endR

\end{document}
```

But with `XeLaTeX` the output is

[image]

Is XeLaTeX implementing `TeX--XeT` differently? If so, why?

Comment: a good question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The LaTeX kernel loads the OpenType version of Latin Modern with XeTeX and LuaTeX. This causes XeTeX to use the HarfBuzz font shaper, and that doesn't really integrate with TeX--XeT. You can force loading of a classical 8-bit font, and the 'original' behaviour is restored:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}

\TeXXeTstate=1

\begin{document}

Hello World

\beginR Hello World\endR
\end{document}
```

Comment: Fundamentally, TeX--XeT is a problematic approach: we are working on helping people transition from XeTeX to LuaTeX as a result. See https://github.com/latex3/xxetex for current ideas.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! LuaTeX has been developing fairly fast in the past few years and it indeed became a suitable alternative, I was just wondering out of curiosity about this phenomenon.

Comment: Does this happen with any OpenType font? I tried to load Times New Roman (without `fontspec`) and got the same behavior.

Comment: @UdiFogiel 'The same behaviour' - could you clarify what output you get?

Comment: The line `\beginR Hello World\endR` produce: World Hello and not dlroW olleH

Comment: @UdiFogiel That's what I'd expect: this is not a macro-level thing, it's how OpenType fonts work with XeTeX. Like I said, `\beginR` is not really integrated at all into font shaping.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thank for clarifying!

Comment: @UdiFogiel it would work with a RTL script opentype font, eg `xepersian` uses opentype fonts but hb sees the `H` which is strongly LTR and so returns the glyphs in LTR order....

Comment: Slight correction, this is not related to HarfBuzz. When using “native” fonts (i.e. not TFM fonts), XeTeX will apply Unicode BiDi algorithm to chunks of text regardless of the TeX--XeT direction (here it is applied to every word separately, but with `\XeTeXinterwordspaceshaping` it will collect more text if it can). This seems to be intentional and predates the use of HarfBuzz. I assume it was so that short strings can get away without needing `\beginR`/`\endR`, etc.