How can I do boustrophedon typesetting in XeLaTeX?
How can I set a paragraph in boustrophedon (i.e., with characters in odd lines set left to right, and characters in even lines set right to left) in XeLaTeX?  I don't want the shape of the characters mirrored, as in these answers; I just want their order reversed.  I am looking for a single command that I can apply to the entire paragraph, without having to figure out line breaks manually.
The two answers posted at Typesetting alternating text left to right and right to left do not work for me:

Steven B. Segletes's answer depends on an obsolete version of the readarray package.
When run in XeLaTeX, Robert's answer reverses the order of the words in even lines, rather than reversing the order of the characters.  (It does work properly with pdflatex.)


Robert's answer comes down to \beginR am a little text\endR behaving differently in the two engines.  I don't know enough to say more.

I've never heard of this, so I had to look it up. I added the link in case others want to read more.

Is there a reason you need xetex instead of luatex? Unless you are typesetting Chinese (and even then, I think) you should probably use luatex. And I imagine Robert's answer can be adapted to luatex primitives

@mbert I suppose I could use LuaTeX instead.  I will give your answer a try and report back.

off-topic: Why unmirrored? looking at [mbert's examples] (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/732575/112216), RTL lines are [to me] much harder to read, I'd say because words don't have their usual shape. I'd expect mirrored RTL to be a bit easier to read...

@PabloH Because the language I'm typesetting doesn't mirror the characters in alternate lines.

@Psychonaut: Different traditions of boustrophedon writing (historical and extant) have different standard conventions.  Some mirror the characters, some rotate them 180º, some (like presumably OP’s) keep them fixed and just reverse the order.

Oh! More off-topic: for anyone doing boustrophedon for speed reading, "On the Legibility of Mirror-Reflected and Rotated Text" suggest 180° rotation may be even faster to read.

If you are willing to use luatex, Robert's answer can be adapted using the luatex primitive \textdir.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\newbox\textbox
\newbox\linebox
\newif\ifrtl
\def\ltrrtl#1{%
  \setbox\textbox=\vbox{#1}%
  \rtlfalse
  \loop\ifvbox\textbox
    \vbadness=10000
    \splittopskip0pt
    \setbox\linebox\vsplit\textbox to\baselineskip
    \unvbox\linebox\setbox\linebox=\lastbox
    \hbox to \hsize{\ifrtl\textdir TRT\fi\unhbox\linebox}%
    \ifrtl\rtlfalse\else\rtltrue\fi
  \repeat
}
\begin{document}
\ltrrtl{\kant[1-2]}
\end{document}


Just like xetex, luatex is a unicode engine and allows the use of opentype fonts.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}
\newbox\textbox
\newbox\linebox
\newif\ifrtl
\def\ltrrtl#1{%
  \setbox\textbox=\vbox{#1}%
  \rtlfalse
  \loop\ifvbox\textbox
    \vbadness=10000
    \splittopskip0pt
    \setbox\linebox\vsplit\textbox to\baselineskip
    \unvbox\linebox\setbox\linebox=\lastbox
    \hbox to \hsize{\ifrtl\textdir TRT\fi\unhbox\linebox}%
    \ifrtl\rtlfalse\else\rtltrue\fi
  \repeat
}
\begin{document}
\ltrrtl{\kant[1-2]}
\end{document}


There are very few reasons to use xetex over luatex nowadays. I think Chinese typesetting (specifically interword space) is one place luatex is inferior, but if I understand correctly this is mostly handled by callbacks in the luatexja package which is loaded by the ctex package/classes.
Edit
As mentioned in the comments, it seems luatex sets the ligatures before reversing the text direction (or some approximation of that). I don't know how to fix this so that the ligatures are reversed - suggestions welcome! - but you can disable ligatures with fontspec options. Here's some code that disables ligatures within the \ltrrtl command. I am not sure if more ligatures need to be disabled than those disabled by CommonOff.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}
\newfontfamily\ScholaNoLigs{TeX Gyre Schola}[Ligatures=CommonOff]
\newbox\textbox
\newbox\linebox
\newif\ifrtl
\def\ltrrtl#1{%
  \setbox\textbox=\vbox{\ScholaNoLigs #1}%
  \rtlfalse
  \loop\ifvbox\textbox
    \vbadness=10000
    \splittopskip0pt
    \setbox\linebox\vsplit\textbox to\baselineskip
    \unvbox\linebox\setbox\linebox=\lastbox
    \hbox to \hsize{\ifrtl\textdir TRT\fi\unhbox\linebox}%
    \ifrtl\rtlfalse\else\rtltrue\fi
  \repeat
}
\begin{document}
\ltrrtl{\kant[1-2]}

first (correct ligatures)

{\ScholaNoLigs first (disable ligatures)}
\end{document}



Amazing.  One tiny rough edge: it looks like ligatures are currently always merged as for LtR before reversing — e.g. first currently appears as tsrﬁ on line 4, presumably ought to be rendered as tsrif.  So presumably ligatures should be (ideally) directionally-aware so that if, half would get their ligatures ﬁ, ﬂah in RtL, or if that’s not possible, then disabled.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Good eye. I disabled ligatures in the edit but I don't know how to enable them in the reverse direction

Thanks; this works for me!  In my case ligatures aren't an issue, though it's nice to know there's a way to account for them in the general case.

@Psychonaut The actually interesting part of the code was written by Robert in his answer so be sure to thank him too!

It occurs to me that if you were ok with mirroring the characters on the R-L lines, you could modify the output routine to disassemble the output box before \shipout and reassemble it line by line applying \reflectbox (from the graphics package) on each line. Of course, if this is just for an excerpt it becomes simpler to do since you can typeset the paragraph inside a \vbox, then disassemble it. More work than I care to do on a quick work break though.

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/673113/107497.  If you add \usepackage[OT1]{fontenc} to Robert's answer, it works.

Not in the general case, it doesn't.  This interferes with the ability to set a font via fontspec (which AFAIK is the reason most people use XeLaTeX in the first place).
